# Duplicates account not displayed in the report

Tags: reporting, account, duplicate-management, duplicate-matching-rule

Hello,

I disabled the standard account duplicate rule because it shows accounts which has no duplicate records.

I created a new matching rule based on the exact account name and I created a duplicate rule which uses the new account matching rule.
Both are enabled.
[image]
[image]

I created a custom report type on the account as the primary object and on the duplicate record items as the second object.
[image]

I know I have some duplicate accounts in my Salesforce but when I create the report for duplicate accounts, Salesforce tells my there is no duplicate accounts in Salesforce.

Can you tell me why please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have feel the difference of your `Duplicate Rule` and `Report object relationship`, So I think that may be the cause you have missed the duplicate accounts in your account report.

In your `Duplicate Rule` - You're said the matching rule as the **same name having accounts are possible duplicate in your org**.

But in your `Report object relationship` you have taken the account with or at least one `Duplicate Record Items` record. *So that report can't include the accounts which are doesn't have any `Duplicate Record Items` records linked*.

So if `A & B` accounts having same name and `A` having one `Duplicate Record Items`record and `B` doesn't means, you're report only show `A` not both.

Please let me know if it helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I only want duplicate accounts in the reapport.
THe aim of the report is to show account duplicates in Salesforce.

So I think it's OK if in the report type, I set accounts with a least one duplicate items.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find the answer or any alternative to the problem?

Anyways, for your information, records existing before the creation of duplicate & matching rules are not included in reports automatically. It requires running [Duplicate jobs from setup](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.duplicate_jobs_run_and_manage.htm&type=5). However, duplicate jobs are only available for Performance and Unlimited Edition. That means, for other editions, the duplicates existing before the rule have to be extracted via some other method. for instance, executing a SOQL or integrating a third-party reporting tool.

If you found some alternate method to include duplicate records in your report, you may share with us as well.